# Can wget create directory structure same as link?

Tags: linux, pdf, download, wget

I have few pdf links from various websites.
example:

[www.example.com/excel/1.pdf](http://www.example.com/excel/1.pdf)

How I can wget that link so 1.pdf is downloaded in /example.com/excel/1/ directory. Can wget auto create the directory path without manually creating or defining that path in wget command?

Comment: StackOverflow is dedicated to helping solve programming code problems.  Your Q **may be**  more appropriate for [su]  ,  but read their help section regarding on-topic questions. AND please read [Help On-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/Help/On-topic) and [Help How-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/Help/How-to-ask) before posting more Qs here.  Good luck.

Answer (score 3):

While the other answer is technically correct, it's not the best way to do things.

Wget can do exactly what the OP is looking for with the `-x, --force-directories` option. Quoting the manual page:

```
   -x
   --force-directories
       The opposite of -nd---create a hierarchy of directories, even if one would not have been created otherwise.  E.g. wget -x http://fly.srk.fer.hr/robots.txt will save the
       downloaded file to fly.srk.fer.hr/robots.txt.
```

So, all you want is:

```
wget -x www.example.com/excel/1.pdf
```

Comment: Yes, This is exactly what I was asking for.

Comment: If it answered your question, please mark it as the correct answer

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can.
You can with the switch O And do the desired address

wget  -O /path/to/file.ext

Also by order curl Do the same Just instead O Great from O Use small. And in the end you have to repeat this operation for the rest in any way you can, for example if you have numerical naming and the numbers only increase, repeat the command with a simple or a loop

Comment: $ wget -x url 
is what i was looking for, I wanted to avoid defining directory on my own as i had lot of urls to download.
Now every file can automatically go into directory similar to url structure.

Comment: Sorry, I did not pay attention to this point